# DataGrid column validation error template

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, xaml, datagrid

I've got a `DataGrid` with a `DataGridTextColumn` which needs some validation.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Width="100">
<DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <Binding Path="Key">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:DistinctValidation/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```

The `DataGrid` itself has no style applied to it, but the `DataGridTextColumn` has the following one:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                <Popup HorizontalAlignment="Left" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="true">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

For simplicity I tried to set the `IsOpen` on the Popup always to true. Nevertheless the popup never shows up
[image: Popup]

Comment: Could you please post your code of the DistinctValidation? I'm also looking for a proper solution to prevent that duplicates could occure in the DataGrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the Validation.ErrorTemplate property of the EditingElementStyle of the column for your template to get applied:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Test}">
  <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                        <Popup HorizontalAlignment="Left" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="true">
                            <Grid Background="White">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Works as expected! Thanks very much